# From a deck of 52-playing cards, 5 cards are drawn. How many 5-card hands are there consisting of 3 face cards, 1 king, and 1 spade?

Tags: combinatorics

From a deck of $52$-playing cards, $5$ cards are drawn. How many $5$-card hands are there consisting of $3$ face cards, $1$ king, and $1$ spade?

Solution:
This can be shown in two cases:
Case 1: If king is not drawn,we have
$\displaystyle \binom{8}{3} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{4}{1}= 896 $ ways

Case 2:
If king is drawn,
$\displaystyle \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{4}{1}= 48 $  ways

Hence, the total number of ways is $896+48= 944$ ways.

Is the solution presented above is conclusively correct?

Comment: With replacement or without?

Comment: This is without replacement. Hoping for your solution on this problem. I find it difficult if without replacement. If with replacement, my answer is 12C3 * 4C1 * 13C1

Comment: A face card could be a spade, as could a king.

Comment: I just used a straight forward method i.e to find and evaluate all the possibilities. Like when the Face card has $0$ spades, $1$ spades ..... $3$ spades with the dependency of king an non kings. It took me 45 minutes. If you want I can post the solution, but It's a little messy.

Comment: Kindly post your solution for everyone's .

Comment: Ok, sure just wait a little.

Comment: @MarkLarson Mark the answer given by *Joriki* as the best of all.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you mean that the five cards can be divided into three face cards, a king and a spade (and not just that they contain three cards, contain a king and contain a spade, possibly overlapping).

Let’s count separately depending on whether the spade is also a face card.

If the spade is a face card, we have $5$ face cards, of which at least one is a spade and at least one is a king. There are $\binom{12}5$ hands with $5$ face cards, of which $\binom95$ have no spade, $\binom85$ have no king and $\binom65$ have neither, so by inclusion–exclusion that makes $\binom{12}5-\binom95-\binom85+\binom65$. But now we’ve counted hands with only the king of spades and no other king and no other spade, of which there are $\binom64$, so we have to subtract those.

If the spade is not a face card, we have one of $10$ non-face-card spades, and $4$ face cards, of which one is a king. There are $\binom{12}4$ sets of $4$ face cards, of which $\binom84$ have no king, so that makes $10\left(\binom{12}4-\binom84\right)$.

Thus, in total, there are $\binom{12}5-\binom95-\binom85+\binom65-\binom64+10\left(\binom{12}4-\binom84\right)=4851$ such hands.

Since this doesn’t agree with another answer that’s been posted, I wrote [Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/f0cb012e8d9367e5aff7d667aecad842) to check it by enumeration.

Comment: "If the spade is a face card, we have 5 face cards" ? Do we not have 3 Spade face cards (namely  Jack, Quuen, King) ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi I'm afraid I don't understand the question. By "we have", do you mean in the deck or in the hand? There are indeed 3 face cards of spades in the deck. I don't see why you seem to think that that contradicts the sentence from my answer that you quoted. The hand consists of three face cards, a king and a spade. The king is a face card. If the spade is also a face card, then all five cards in the hand are face cards. What does that have to do with the number of face cards of spades in the deck?

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that earlier, sorry.

Comment: By " we have " I meant in deck.

Comment: My answer when I recalculated came to be $8640$. Please read my answer and make me understand why my answer is so different..

Comment: I am not clear with the idea you used. Can you elaborate for the number of choices in hand for the cases taken above ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi: I'm afraid I can't follow your calculations. As regards my answer: If I repsonded to general requests of the form "can you elaborate" about answers with several paragraphs, I'd be spending most of my life on math.SE. Please ask a more specific question about a part that you don't understand.

Comment: Ok, "But now we’ve counted hands with only the king of spades and no other king and no other spade, of which there are $\binom {6}{4}$, so we have to subtract those." I didn't get that how ?

Comment: In my answer, are my conditions not valid ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi: I counted by inclusion–exclusion the hands with $5$ face cards that contain a king and contain a spade. But there was nothing to ensure that these are two different cards; hands that contain the king of spades were also counted, even if they contain no other king and no other spade. But these hands don't consist of three face cards, a king, and a spade; so we have to subtract them. There are $6$ face cards that are neither a king nor a spade, so there are $\binom64$ such hands.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi: I don't understand your answer and I don't intend to invest the time to understand it. That's why I wrote a short Java program to check which (if any) of the results is correct. If you want to know what's wrong with your answer, I'd recommend asking a question about it. These comments about my answer are not the place for that discussion.

Comment: Ok, I got that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105429/discussion-between-nikola-alfredi-and-joriki).

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi: Sorry, this is taking too much of my time. I'm sure you're capable of counting the number of face cards that are not spade and not king and those that are not spade or not king and deciding for yourself. (If not, I'd recommend doing easier problems first.)

Comment: This, was a bit rude ! but no issues, Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: I understood your answer completely and it seems correct and have covered all the possibilities .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

You can create cases for King and Spade card for each of these cases....